# Transformar una columna de fechas con formato string a otra con formate datetime

Tags: python, datetime, date, formato

Tengo un archivo `.csv` con 2 columnas, el índice del `DataFrame` y una columna time con fechas en el formato `string` tal que `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`:

```
,time
0,2015-01-01 09:26:27
1,2015-01-01 09:26:37
2,2015-01-01 09:26:47
...
```

Necesito convertir cada una de estas fechas a otro archivo en el cual estén en formato `datetime` para poder plotearlo junto con otros conjuntos de datos. Ya he estado mirando que para la conversión se utiliza:

```
df_datetime = datetime.strptime('2015-01-01 09:26:27', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Mi problema viene que estoy intentando crear un bucle que recorra la columna de `time`, vaya transformando las fechas con el comando de arriba y me las guarde en una nueva variable para luego exportarlo como un `.csv` de `datetimes` y poder trabajar con él. ¿Alguna idea no muy complicada de como hacerlo? Mil gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu archivo es:

```
,time
0,2015-01-01 09:26:27
1,2015-01-01 09:26:37
2,2015-01-01 09:26:47
```

Código para leer la columna time(en formato datetime):

```
import csv, datetime
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list) # each value in each column is appended to a list

with open('test3.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f) # read rows into a dictionary format
    for row in reader: # read a row as {column1: value1, column2: value2,...}
        for (k,v) in row.items(): # go over each column name and value 
            columns[k].append(v) # append the value into the appropriate list
                                 # based on column name k

print(columns['time'])
# Imprimiendo en formato datetime
for fecha in columns['time']:
    df_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print(df_datetime)
```

Código para guardar en un csv.

```
#guardando en un csv
with open("Datetime.csv","w") as csvFile:
    Fileout = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)   
    for fecha in columns['time']:
        df_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        Fileout.writerow([df_datetime])
```

Referencias: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16503661/4968795

Comment: Gracias! Me funcionó!